# Failure opening SSH to Mac OS X 10.10 using .Net

Tags: .net, macos, ssh

I am attempting to open a simple SSH connection to a Mac OS PC from my .Net code using the SSH.NET library. It works flawlessly when attempting to connect to a Linux PC but fails when attempting to connect to a Mac.
Here's my code:

```
SshClient ssh = new SshClient("myURL", 22, "myUsername", "myPass);

        {
            ssh.Connect();
            var result = ssh.RunCommand("df -h");
            ssh.Disconnect();

        }
```

The log file mentions:
Apr 20 18:12:56 mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.FA1D901D-E641-4515-B43B-8E15B3478633[2059]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

On Visual Studio I am getting the following error when running:
No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication.

Comment: Also: (com.openssh.sshd.63287FC6-7743-4893-8597-ACA812774A17): Service instances do not support events yet.

Comment: Bumping back to the top

Answer (score 1):

Ran across the same problem as .Net for a Node.js ssh connection , but here is how I fixed it on Yosemite.10.10.5

sudo vi /private/etc/sshd_config

set PasswordAuthentication to yes `PasswordAuthentication yes`

```
    sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
    sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, managed to dig the solution:
In this case you should go to your Mac's sshd_config file and change the "PasswordAuthentication no" to "PasswordAuthentication yes" and unquote it if it's quoted.